# Returning to main menu from another inner menu using c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I thought of making a sort of Point Of Sales (POS) program. So, as you open the program, a menu (the main menu) would open-up which is a scrolling menu (you can move up & down to select an item in the menu with the arrow keys) and the items in it are like "Start business day", "Stats", "Inventory" blah blah.

Now, when you press "Start Business day"(using enter), you would get another menu which would ask for things like "Take order " ........"Return to the main menu". This is where I am finding the problem. When I press "Return to the main menu", I am not able to move back to the main menu.

MY ATTEMPT

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int chk=0;

int sbd(void) //the order menu (start business day -> ' press ENTER')
{
        int pointer=0;
        string order[4]={"TAKE ORDER","CHECK MENU","MEMO","RETURN TO MAIN MENU"};



     while(true)
     {
         system("cls");
         SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),14);

        cout<<"\t\t     ZAIKA KATHI ROLLS\n";
        cout<<"\t\t\tORDER MENU\n\n";

         for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
         {
             if( i==pointer)
             {
                 SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),11);
                 cout<<"-> "<<order[i]<<endl<<endl;
             }
             else
             {
                 SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),15);
                 cout<<"   "<<order[i]<<endl<<endl;
             }
         }
            while(true)
             {
                  if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)!=0)
                  {
                      pointer-=1;
                      if(pointer==-1)
                      {
                           pointer=3;
                      }

                      break;
                  }
                   else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)!=0)
                   {
                       pointer+=1;
                       if(pointer==4)
                       {
                         pointer=0;
                       }

                    break;
                   }
                   else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)!=0)
                   {
                       switch(pointer)
                       {
                           case 3 : return 1;
                       }
                   }
             }
             Sleep(150);
         }





}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{


    int pointer=0;
    int flag=1;
    string menu[6]={"START BUSINESS DAY","CONTINUE BUSINESS DAY","END BUSINESS DAY","INVENTORY MANAGEMENT","STATISTICS","SETTINGS"};

Mainmenu :        while(true)
        {
            system("cls");
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),14);
            int i=0;

            cout<<"\t\t     ZAIKA KATHI ROLLS\n";
            cout<<"\t\t\tMAIN MENU\n\n";

            for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
            {

                if(i==pointer)
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),11);
                    cout<<"-> "<<menu[i]<<endl<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),15);
                    cout<<"   "<<menu[i]<<endl<<endl;
                }

            }
            while(true)
            {
                if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)!=0)
                 {
                     pointer-=1;



                     if(pointer==-1)
                     {
                          pointer=5;
                     }
                    break;
                }
                else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)!=0)
                {
                    pointer+=1;

                   /* if(flag==0 && pointer==1)
                        pointer=3;

                    if(flag==1 && pointer==0)
                        pointer=1;*/

                    if(pointer==6)
                    {
                         pointer=0;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)!=0)
                {
                    switch(pointer)
                    {
                        case 0 :chk=sbd();

                                if(chk==1)
                                    goto Mainmenu;






                    }
                }

            }

            Sleep(150);
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

The best idea that came to my mind was to make the "start business day" as a function and in that function as we press "Return to main menu",the function will return a value which the main fuction will detect and then by using the goto fuction the program control will transfer to the main menu.Apparently thats not working, so can anyone please help me out of this?

Comment: What's SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),14);?

Comment: Well, it simply colours all the text that comes underneath  it(14 is the colour code for bright yellow)

Comment: @Zebrafish You can run the code and see it for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that when you press enter on "Return to main menu" it is in fact going back to the main menu. If you debug and step through it you'll see this. The problem is that as soon as it steps out of the sub-menu loop it goes into the main menu loop, checks to see if "enter" was pressed, passes the condition and enters the sub-menu loop again.

The thing is that you're not using GetAsyncKeyState function properly in your code:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
```

It checks whether the value is zero. But according to the docs this function returns a SHORT.

The most significant bit is 1 if the key is pressed down, and 0 if not.

The least significant bit is 1 if the key was pressed since last calling GetAsyncKeyState. I assume this is what you want. So to begin with change the two spots in your code:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
```

to:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x01 != 0)
```

We only want to check the least significant bit to see if the key was pressed since last time that function was called. If you do this it should work.

You can also write it like this using the Windows macro:

```
if (LOBYTE(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)) != 0)
```

I should also mention you should probably get around to doing it this same way for key up and key down.

I really like it though, nice work.

Edit: GetAsyncKeyState() returns a short integer. It's most likely two bytes. When the function returns with this value it sets certain bits or flags to tell you information. Like I said, the most significant bit (the highest) tells you whether the key is down or not, the lowest significant bit tells you if the key has been pressed since the last call to that function.

So the returned number in binary will look like this (MSB) is most significant and (LSB) is least significant:

```
10000000 00000001
^ MSB           ^ LSB
```

If this were an unsigned integer its value would be 32769. You're not interested in whether the key is currently down, but more interested in whether the key has been pressed since the last call to the function. You're only interested in the bit on the right. The bitwise operator & AND will compare two bit patterns and if and only if BOTH bits are 1, it will set the resulting bit to one. This is used with a mask so you can pluck out certain values, so to speak.

```
10000000 00000001 // Original value
00000000 00000001 // The mask
00000000 00000001 // Result
```

The result is 1. Then you can check whether the value is 1, and if it is then the key was pressed since the last call. It's a very low level way of doing things, but that's kinda how Windows works and Windows actually helps out by providing that macro LOBYTE() which does the same thing. The alternative is the function could have returned class/struct with bool values for each thing instead.

SECOND EDIT (FURTHER EXPLANATION):

The least significant bit will only be 1 if the key was pressed down since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState. So if you press down the enter key and keep it pressed for 3 seconds, the LSB will be set only on the first call to GetAsyncKeyState. However the MSB will continue to return with the MSB set, because this indicates whether the key is down. The following quick program should illustrate this nicely I think.

A short in our case has 2(bytes) 16 bits, so we're going to use the right bitshift operator >> to get it. I'm going to convert the return type from SHORT to USHORT. This is because bitshifting is undefined for signed integers which are negative because right shifting can propagate the leftmost bit. For example:

```
// Right shifting 7 bits
UNSIGNED INT
1000 0000 >> 7 = 0000 0001

SIGNED INT
1000 0000 >> 7 = 1111 1111 // We may get this instead which is not what we want
```

Start a new project and paste this and run, try pressing the enter key:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int count = 0;
        USHORT funcResult = 0;

        while ((funcResult = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)) != 0) 
            // If MSB or LSB is set then condition is true
        {
            count++;
            cout << "Return pressed " << count << " times in one loop\n";
            cout << "MSB = " << (funcResult >> 15) << '\n';
            cout << "LSB = " << (funcResult & 1) << '\n';
        }
            // You will see that the MSB is always 1, because it tells us
            // if the key is down.

            // However the LSB is 1 only on the first run of the while loop
    }
}
```

So this is why adding Sleep() also fixes the problem, because if you press down the enter key for 400 ms and let go, and make the thread sleep for 500 ms, next time it checks the key won't be down, and the MSB won't be set.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on the Least Significant Bit case ? I am not quite clear with it.

Comment: @Rohan I've added a bit extra to the answer. That's a cool menu system, especially written completely in the command prompt.

Comment: Look, the problem with my code was that when I press Enter in the sub-menu the program control reaches the main menu which again considers the Enter key and reaches the sub menu. So, basically the issue was that the smallest amount of time I take to press the Enter key is a lot of time for the program and so it considers it to be the case of "pressing the key ever since the last call"(It's totally what I understood from your very detailed and helpful answer, please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: (Sorry , ran out of space :( )The correction that you suggested me works with a charm but I still didn't understand how it works. See,I think that we must consider the case of "NOT pressing the key ever since the last call of the function " now, according to the fault the function is returning a SHORT with LSB=1 and after that when we use the bitwise & with 00000001 we get 1 which is not equal to zero which was the case even before we used '&' . So how is it working? I am really sorry for troubling you again.

Comment: @Rohan No trouble, it's good to be curious. I was really confused about how this GetAsyncKeyState  function worked. I've added a further Edit at the bottom with a test program to show you what happens when you press a key down and which bits are set.